# How to fetch dependencies of a resource using .NET Azure SDK?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create an alternative to using ARM templates.

I have so far managed to fetch subscriptions, resource groups and resource details using apropriate clients in SDK (ResourceManagementClient, SubscriptionClient), however I couldnt find a way to fetch the dependsOn portion of the template.

Is this even supported, and if it is, how do I do it?

Comment: `dependsOn` is specific to ARM template. If you call the API directly you wont have the information you re looking for. Also there are other tools if you dont want to use ARM temaplte such as Bicep, Terraform, Az CLI.

Comment: [ArmDependency.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/11a480bbd723bcb7ed6b1bdfb638fbece2b2b1d5/sdk/resources/Azure.ResourceManager.Resources/src/Generated/Models/ArmDependency.cs)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this even supported, and if it is, how do I do it?

Currently, there is **no support** for getting the **dependsOn** value.

The [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/resource-dependency#dependson) says that **dependsOn** isn't the best option because of how resources are interconnected. Because the resource's properties **do not** maintain deployment **dependencies after deployment**, there are **no commands or actions** that allow you to see **dependencies.**